# getting "missing ; before statement" error when trying to use eval in mongodb shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

[image]

I want to try out executing javascript from mongo shell. 
mongo test --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"

However, I'm getting the error as you can see on the above screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "--eval" option is used in [Scripted mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo), you should not be already connected to the shell. Use that as in an example below:

```
mongo YOUR_DB_NAME --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
```

Comment: ah, tnx Oleksandr :-)